# Using Linq query, how can I write if condition in join?

Tags: c#, linq

My database looks like this:

Priority

```
ROLE_ID(pk)     Department
---------------------------
1               Admin
2               Hr
3               Sales
```

This table is referred to from the Fat table:

```
Id  Email              ROLE_ID (FK)
-----------------------------------
1   abc@gmail.com          1
2   xyz@gmail.com          2
3   lmn@gmail.com          3
4   Jeams@gmail.com        3
5   ANder@gmail.com        3
```

When I'm trying to get record priority(1) and I need all Priority(3) records

Then how can I come to know `He is Hr And He is Admin`

**Linq**

```
    public IEnumerable<Ems_UserFat_Tab> GetUserFatData()
    {
        var x = from n in db.EMS_USER_MASTER
                join prio in db.Ems_priority_Master on n.USER_PRIORITY equals prio.User_Priority_ID
                where n.ROLE_ID==3  &&  prio.User_Priority_ID==1               
                select new Ems_UserFat_Tab
                {         

               Sh_Email= n.EMAIL,

                };  

        return x.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand - what is wrong with your query? What results do you want? Where is 'ROLE_ID' in your tables? Is 'prio.User_Priority_ID' the same as ID in the Prioty table?

Comment: @RobinBennett I was just Update dmy question

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Your LINQ looks ok to me, what results do you get? and what do you want?

Comment: .where (n.ROLE_ID==1  || n.ROLE_ID==2) &&  prio.User_Priority_ID==1               
                select new    {         
               IsAdmin = n.ROLE_ID = 1,
              IsHr = n.RoleId = 2,
               Sh_Email= n.EMAIL

                };

Comment: But your users have single roles, or is possible to have more than one record for an email in EMS_USER_MASTER?

Comment: If so you need to group by Email and then select

Comment: You wrote: "When im trying to getting Recored priority(1) and i need all Priority(3) Record Then How can i come to Know He is Hr And He is Admin Linq". Really, quite incomprehensible. If you are not wiling to write a proper requirement, how do you expect us to give you a proper answer?